# Sync git repo with existing files

Tags: git

Okay, so I was working with a developer. We keep all our changes within git.

What by mistake happened was he didn't clone the repo instead he copy pasted the entire repo without the .git folder and has made changes to it.

What we want is to sync the repo with git and also commit the changes done.

What would be the proper procedure to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If the developer has access to the path where the original `.git/` folder is, all he/she needs to do is to set the environment variable `GIT_DIR` to that `.git/` path (which can be simply after having clone again that repo in another path).
And `GIT_WORK_TREE` to the current working tree folder (the one where modifications have been made).

See [Git Environment variables "Repository locations"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations).

From there, automagically, any git command will reflect the state of the Git repository, like `git status`, `git add`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to just **copy** all files from the directory that the changes were made and **paste** them on the cloned repository directory.

Git automatically will track the changes and show what files were changed with `git status`. So, you just need to commit the files.